# On convergence rate of kernel approximation

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{K_\epsilon\}$ be a sequence of mollifiers, (or often take heat kernels).  We have known from classical analysis that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then the error 
$$||f-f*K_\epsilon||_\infty\to 0$$
as $\epsilon\to 0$. I wish to know an explicit upper bound for that convergence rate as a function of $\epsilon,f$. Will the regularity of $f$ and $K$ influence the global sup-norm convergence rate in this context? Any comment shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is highly dependent on your choice of $K$. I'm not sure how much could be said without knowing what $K$ is explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ with $\int f=1$, $\forall \epsilon>0$ let $f_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-n}f(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ then  $\parallel g-g\ast f_{\epsilon}\parallel_{\infty}\rightarrow0$ when $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ if $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The proof can be found in Fourier Analysis - Duoandikoetxea j.